# Pass Spring Boot jar name to Gradle Groovy script

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have a gradle script that runs after the SpringBoot jar file is generated:

```
task runScript (dependsOn: 'bootJar', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'postpackage'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

So far, the gradle script just prints a message:

```
println "hello world from groovy version ${GroovySystem.version}"
```

This works fine in my build.

> gradle runScript
>
> > Task :runScript  hello world from groovy version 2.4.15

What I want is something like:

```
println "hello world generated jar file name is ${jarFileName}"
```

What I want to do is pass in the SpringBoot generated jar name, or the name of the jar in `build/libs/my-service-0.1.1.jar` or whatever it is.

So it would print:

> hello world generated jar file name is my-service-0.1.1.jar

How can I do that?

Here is what I tried:

postpackage.groovy:

```
println "hello world from groovy version ${GroovySystem.version}"

println "hello world from groovy version $bootJar.archiveName"
```

build.gradle:

```
task runScript (dependsOn: 'bootJar', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'postpackage'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Here's the error:

> Task :runScript FAILED
>   hello world from groovy version 2.4.15 Exception in thread "main"
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bootJar for
>   class: postpackage
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:66)

Comment: you can configure bootJar task like `bootJar{ archiveName = project.property('theFileName') }` and then use commandline parameter : `./gradlew -PtheFileName="the-target-name.jar"`

Comment: I added exactly what I am looking for

Comment: then try `println "hello world generated jar file name is $bootJar.archiveName"`

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bootJar for class: postpackage`

Comment: See the edits - I used `$bootJar.archiveName` and `${$bootJar.archiveName}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Pass the argument via the build.gradle like this:

```
task runScript (dependsOn: 'bootJar', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'postpackage'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args "${bootJar.archiveName}"
}
```

Reference it in the script like this:

```
println "hello world from groovy version ${GroovySystem.version}"

println "hello world from groovy version ${args[0]}"
```

Works just fine:

> :bootJar UP-TO-DATE :runScript hello world from groovy version 2.4.15
>
> hello world from groovy version my-service-0.1.1.jar
>
> ```
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
> 5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
> 12:36:00 PM: Task execution finished 'runScript'.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reference the bootjar as "jar".

Example of your print statement:

```
println "hello world from groovy version ${jar.archiveName}"
```